# Как добавить картинкам на сайте зернистость и искажение при наведении?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, эффекты

Из названия уже понятна суть: есть простые картинки на сайте, добавляемые при помощи `<img>`. При наведении на любую картинку срабатывает анимация искажения. Искажение должно выглядеть в точности, как на [примере](https://www.nightingale.world/projects/), в котором это всё реализовано. Также я ещё хочу добавить второй эффект, который всегда будет показываться: зернистость. Тоже, как в примере.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Именно такое чудо я и хочу придать картинкам и на своей странице. Существует ли подходящая для этой задачи библиотека и как это грамотно реализовывают?

Comment: Помимо картинок, на этом сайте используется [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API). Статья на англ. с примерами кода эффекта дисторсии — для иллюстрации, насколько всё может быть не просто: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/10/08/creating-a-water-like-distortion-effect-with-three-js/

Comment: Сложности не боюсь. Английский даётся мне легко, а ресурс, который вы мне подкинули очень мне поможет. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал так

```js
'use strict';

console.clear();

//настройки шума, тут покрутишь найдешь нужное.
class Grain {
  constructor (el) {
    this.patternSize = 150;
    this.patternScaleX = 1;
    this.patternScaleY = 1;
    this.patternRefreshInterval = 1;
    this.patternAlpha = 35; 

    this.canvas = el;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.ctx.scale(this.patternScaleX, this.patternScaleY);
    this.patternCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.patternCanvas.width = this.patternSize;
    this.patternCanvas.height = this.patternSize;
    this.patternCtx = this.patternCanvas.getContext('2d');
    this.patternData = this.patternCtx.createImageData(this.patternSize, this.patternSize);
    this.patternPixelDataLength = this.patternSize * this.patternSize * 4; // rgba = 4
    this.resize = this.resize.bind(this);
    this.loop = this.loop.bind(this);
    
    this.frame = 0;
    
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize);
    this.resize();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop);
  }
  
  resize () {
    this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth * devicePixelRatio;
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight * devicePixelRatio;
  }

  update () {
    const {patternPixelDataLength, patternData, patternAlpha, patternCtx} = this;

    for (let i = 0; i < patternPixelDataLength; i += 4) {
      const value = Math.random() * 255;

      patternData.data[i] = value;
      patternData.data[i + 1] = value;
      patternData.data[i + 2] = value;
      patternData.data[i + 3] = patternAlpha;
    }

    patternCtx.putImageData(patternData, 0, 0);
  }

  draw () {
    const {ctx, patternCanvas, canvas, viewHeight} = this;
    const {width, height} = canvas;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(patternCanvas, 'repeat');
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  }

  loop () {
    const shouldDraw = ++this.frame % this.patternRefreshInterval === 0;
    if (shouldDraw) {
      this.update();
      this.draw();
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop);
  }
}

const el = document.querySelector('.grain');
const grain = new Grain(el);
```

```css
body {
  background-image: urL('https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-06/1560838551_1.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.grain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="grain">
```

Comment: Здорово! Ответ очень полезный! Это как раз тот нужный эффект зернистости, которого я хочу добиться. Большое спасибо!
Пока что попытаюсь разобраться и с тем эффектом и другим. Если не появится ответ лучше вашего, будете награждены лучшим ответом.